# unable to load Assetes class with MY_Assetes in same directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have one third party asset library in my application folder, i am extending that library with MY_Assets library both are in same application/library directory, but when loading its giving error Unable to load the requested class: Assets, i want to add some extra features in library by extending it so if developer of main library make any update nothing effect to mine extension

Comment: I could be wrong, but I am pretty sure CI looks for the library to be in the system/libraries folder when extending with the MY_ naming. It could very well be that it's not looking for it in the application/libraries folder

Comment: @RickCalder See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html towards the bottom of the page. Also, you should *never* have to mess with the system folder at all. Everything can be overriden from the application folder.

Comment: Yeah I understand how that works, but I just wasn't sure when he was trying to extend a 3rd party library and not a core one.

Answer (score 0):

Place the file in application folder and need to include the code manually then extends from it.

See the below code that I uses for extending the Facebook connect for Codeigniter.

```
include(APPPATH.'libraries/facebook/facebook.php');

class Fb_connect extends Facebook{
   //my coding here
}
```

Here I have a folder named facebook inside the libraries folder for facebook related dowloaded files and FB_connect.php is my library file it is in application /libraries folder and fb_connect class that inherits from Facebook class.

Comment: well thank have an idea now i will put require for MY_Assets at bottom of my Assets file same like how i am creating admin_controller and public_controller and putting them in MY_Controller and extending them with my_controller.